# ios8, Back button disappeared in 'NavigationViewController'

Tags: ios, xcode

I am newbie to iOS programming.

The problem is that back button which is belong to 'NavigationViewController',

is suddenly missing when storyboard is changed.

[image] As you see there is back button.

[image] Back button is missing after click the button.

[image] This is starting point from my second storyboard.

```
- (IBAction)resultClick:(UIButton *)sender {
NSLog(@"결과 보기 버튼 클릭");
UIStoryboard *secondStoryboard =[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Second" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *initialSecondVC = [secondStoryboard instantiateInitialViewController];
initialSecondVC.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentViewController:initialSecondVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

}   -> It is action when button clicked in first storyboard.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is because you are specifying your segue to be modal (UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal). 
A modal transition does get pushed to the right, so it does not have a button to go back.

You can either make a push segue (which is the defaul one so remove the line of the style, and make sure the segue in the storyboard is set to push) or add a button (somewhere) that dismisses the segue.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomSegues/CreatingCustomSegues.html

Try custom segue or you can avoid Navigation Bar and put UIButton as back button.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have this line:

```
initialSecondVC.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
```

**UIModal** is a type of Modal segue which acts as creating a new view. If you wish to have the function of the back button you will need to use a Push Segue instead of a Modal. It is one of the options given when you use (ctrl + drag).

If you want to go back but still want the have the nice **transition that Modal makes available** as you have in your code (`UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal`), you need to embed your second View Controller in a Navigation controller and place a UIBarButtonItem in the navigation bar, name it "< back" and connect it as an `-(IBAction) backButton: (UIBarButtonItem) sender;` and use the same code that you are using to go to the second view controller to go back.